# Deploy Azure stack in a hardware with minimal hardware requirements

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-stack

Is there any way to install azure stack development kit in a hardware with 24GB RAM, 1TB HDD and 4Core CPU.

We have tried to modify the power shell script followed the trace to bypass the RAM and CPU minimum requirements. Then we started deployment not by wizard. We executed the script which is being called by the wizard in backend. We dint give any inputs to the script except password.

We used Azure active directory for identity and federation service.

The installation was going up to AzS-ADFS01 and it was stopped. We have check the deployment. Hyperv is is not running, It seems there is some problem in azure stack networking side I guess.

Could you please help me to install azure stack and to evaluate the experience of azure private cloud in my sandbox.

Best Regards,
Radhakrishnan Rk

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Stack installer will configure a couple (10) of machines with a specific amount of memory. Running all these machines together will not work on the amount of memory so the configuration needs to be changed.

The configuration for these machines can be adjusted within a file called “PoCFabricSettings.xml” that you can find in the folder “Drive:\AzureStackInstaller\PoCFabricInstaller”.

https://msftplayground.com/2016/03/installing-azure-stack-laptop-windows-10/

Comment: Not sure he is talking about Service Fabric clusters. Azure Stack is something different.

Comment: In azure stack, we use ADFS for identity, Do we need to add the azure stack development kit host to any active directory domain.

Comment: i believe yes @RadhakrishnanRk https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-run-powershell-script#deploy-the-development-kit

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Microsoft Azure Stack is a hybrid cloud platform that lets you provide Azure services from your datacenter.

Before you deploy Azure Stack Development Kit, make sure your computer meets the following requirements:

[image]

For more details, refer “**[Azure Stack documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/)**”.

Comment: that's misleading, for development purposes you can use even laptops with 32gb.

Comment: Deploying Azure Stack on a laptop with 32 GB is not possible.

The above hardware details is an official hardware prerequisites for Azure Stack deployment.

Kindly check the Azure Stack deployment prerequisites:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-deploy

Comment: https://www.danielstechblog.info/microsoft-azure-stack-technical-preview-on-lower-hardware/ google=hard?

Comment: Could you check the document published date?
Kindly follow the latest documents.

Refer the MSDN thread for information:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/48713059-d25c-4e3b-a245-0fdd424a4449/azure-stack-deployment-in-azure-vm?forum=AzureStack

Comment: even that thread says it can be done. how hard is it to read?